# Image is not displaying on Read the Docs, but it is displayed on Github, what is wrong?

Tags: html, github, markdown, read-the-docs

I am trying to add an image to one of the .md files for our read the docs.

I am putting this on my .md file:

```
<p align="center">
    <img src="github url where the image is" width="350" />
    </a>
</p>
```

Once I commit, It looks fine when I look at the file on Github, but it shows error on Read the docs.

I have tried different file type (.png or .svg), with Mark Down instead of HTML, and the story is always the same: I can see it on Github, but not on read the docs...

Any clues?

Thanks!!!

Comment: I would love to see this solved as well.

Answer (score 0):

Github probably protects his images from hotlinking

Comment: It is an image I uploaded myself... I also have the file in my computer. Is there anyway around it?  Pardon my rookiness ;)

Comment: Upload the image to https://imgur.com/ or any other image host

Comment: Hey, I just tried linking to imgur URL... same story... I can see it on github but not on readthedocs... any other idea?